# How to define file input commands with optional arguments?

Tags: emacs, reftex

So here is the situation : I wanted latex to read some commands when I include another file, and for that I defined a new `\include` command like this :

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{}

\newcommand{\includeas}[2][]{%
   \foo{#1}
   \include{#2}}
```

It works beyond all hopes! But now I'd like to still be able to use RefTeX's toc browser with my new `\includeas` command.

And here is the problem : (from RefTeX's manual)

> User Option: reftex-include-file-commands
>
> List of LaTeX commands which input another file. The file name is expected after the  command, either in braces or separated by whitespace.

As you can see, having an optional argument in square brackets after the macro is a problem for RefTeX.

Is there any way I can bypass it?

At the moment I have a quick fix by turning the optional #1 argument to mandatory #2, but it relies on the fact I actually provide the argument all the time, which won't always be the case.

MWE:

File main.tex

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document} 

\includeas[blabla]{foo} 
 % The test is to press C-C = , not to try to compile!

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

File foo.tex :

```
\chapter{Name}
\label{cha:name}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the argument optional on the flip side of the command:

```
\makeatletter
\def\includeas#1{
    \@ifnextchar[{\includeas@opt{#1}}{\includeas@{#1}}
}
\def\includeas@#1{ 
    \include{#1}
}
\def\includeas@opt#1[#2]{
    \foo{#2}
    \include{#1}
}
\makeatother
```

Then you will call it as:

```
Without optional
\includeas{filename.tex}
With optional
\includeas{filename.tex}[foo]
```

However you should not start a regular sentence with `[` after a use of the command `\includeas`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much.

You last warning is right, but it won't happen, there is about nothing in my main file.

One thing only, for the command to have the intended input, I had to replace the second definition by 
`\def\includeas@#1{
    \foo{Default} 
    \include{#1}
}`
No big deal though. Thanks again!

Comment: Ahh. If you need a default value i would do like this instead:
`\makeatletter
    \def\includeas#1{
        \@ifnextchar[{\includeas@opt{#1}{\includeas@opt{#1}[Default]}
    }
    \def\includeas@opt#1[#2]{
        \foo{#2}
        \include{#1}
    }
    \makeatother`

Comment: Ok thanks, I can see the advantages of this version. :)